# Evaluate limit using definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

I've got this, but i think i took a wrong turn and i don't know what to do next
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \ldots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2} = ?$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \ldots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{k}{n^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: i guess it should be $k^2$ inside that square root not $k$ and $n\to \infty$ not $x$

Comment: The ellipsis at the beginning introduces a pernicious ambiguity:  are we summing $1\le k \le n$ or are we summing with $k^2$, $1\le k \le n$?

Comment: In theory, the ellipsis could hide practically anything. If the OP's reading is taken, the limit is of the arithmetic mean of $n^2$ terms $\ge n$, so diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: I edited my question. Now it's correct.

Comment: Notice that if the ellipses are to be interpreted as you say, then you're summing $n^2$ terms, each of which are greater than $\frac1n$. Thus, the sum is greater than $n$. As $n\to\infty\dots$ I bet there are actually supposed to be $n$ terms $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}\,\frac1n$$

Answer (score 2):

If we assume
$$\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}$$
was intended to mean the sum
$$
\sqrt{n^2 + 1}
+
\sqrt{n^2 + 2}
+
\sqrt{n^2 + 3}
+
\cdots 
+
\sqrt{n^2 + n^2}
$$
of $n^2$ terms, then
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2}\\[4pt]
=\;&\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n^2}\\[2pt]
>\;&\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{n^2}\\[2pt]
=\;&\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{n}\\[2pt]
=\;&n^2\cdot \frac{1}{n}\\[2pt]
=\;&n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2} = \infty$$

Alternatively, applying the concept of Riemann sums,
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^3}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n^3}\\[2pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\\[2pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{k}{n^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\\[2pt]
=\;&\int_0^1\!\sqrt{1+x}\;dx\\[2pt]
=\;&c,\;\text{where}\;c\in(0,\infty)\\[2pt]
\end{align*}
In fact, the actual value of $c$ is ${\large{\frac{4\sqrt{2}-2}{3}}}$, but for the argument that follows, we only need $c\in(0,\infty)$.

So now we have
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^3}\cdot n\\[2pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} c\cdot n\\[2pt]
=\;&c\cdot\!\lim_{n\to\infty} n\\[2pt]
=\;&c\cdot\infty\\[2pt]
=\;&\infty\\[2pt]
\end{align*}
However, noting the comments by Upstart, ncmathsadist, and robjohn, and also Bernard's answer, I suspect that
$$\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}$$
was actually intended to mean
$$
\sqrt{n^2 + 1^2}
+
\sqrt{n^2 + 2^2}
+
\sqrt{n^2 + 3^2}
+ 
\cdots
+
\sqrt{n^2 + n^2}
$$
which is a sum of $n$ terms.

With that assumption,
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1^2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2 + n^2}}{n^2}\\[6pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k^2}}{n^2}\\[6pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k^2}}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\\[6pt]
=\;&\lim_{n\to\infty} \;\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1 + \left({\small{\frac{k}{n}}}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\\[4pt]
=\;&\int_0^1\!\sqrt{1+x^2}\;dx\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{\sqrt{2}-\ln\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}{2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: You're right. But can we solve it using Riemann sum?

Comment: @Jerome D Walker: I've updated my answer to show an alternative argument using Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

I think you should rewrite the sum as
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + k^2}}{n}= \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{n^2 + k^2\strut}{n^2}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{1+\frac{k^2\mathstrut}{n^2}\,.}$$

Comment: But it's not the same sum. $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \sqrt{n^2+k} \neq \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2+k^2} $$

Comment: The form you gave with dots is ambiguous. Are you sure the variable part takes *every* value between $1$ and $n^2$?

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

Without Riemann sums, we could have a quite good approximation using generalized harmonic numbers since
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} \sqrt{n^2+i}=H_{2 n^2}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-H_{n^2}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_{p}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2 p^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24\sqrt{{p}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\right)$$
$$S_n=\frac{2}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right)
   n^3+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\right) n+\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{48
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$\frac{S_n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right)
   n+\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{48
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$

Uisng the above approximation, for $n=10$ we would obtain $\frac{642401 \sqrt{2}-322402}{48000}$ which is $\approx 12.210212639209$ while the exact summation would lead to 
                  $\approx 12.210212639252$